# How does constant change AM-GM

Tags: inequality

If one has the equation

$2^{-x}+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+2016+4^x+3^x+2^x$

Then how is the AM-GM inequality satisfied?
I thought that AM-GM would satisfy
$$\frac{2^{-x}+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+2016+4^x+3^x+2^x}{7}\geq(2016)^\frac{1}{7}$$

And so the minimum value of the LHS is $7\times(2016)^\frac{1}{7}$

When you graph the function the minimum comes out to be 2022 which is guaranteed with an AM-GM inequality without the constant 2016.
How does the constant affect the result and what we generalize about the terms of a sum to satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Good question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with applying the AM-GM equality the way you did is the fact that the equality case $2^x=2^{-x}=3^x=3^{-x}=4^x=4^{-x}=2016$ is impossible, as $2^{x}=2^{-x}$ only when they are both 1.

Since you cannot get equality, you just get that $(2016)^\frac{1}{7}$ is **smaller** than your expression, but have no idea how far or close it is to the minimum.

To get the minimum, you need to apply the AM-GM without the constant, and the add the constant:
$$\frac{2^{-x}+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+4^x+3^x+2^x}{6}\geq 1$$
In this inequality, equality **can be attained**, and is obtained when $x=0$.

Note that your inequality tells you that the LHS is greater than $(2016)^\frac{1}{7}$, which is true since it the LHS is greater than $2022$, but far from optimal.

Comment: In the second line of the question, I don't see any **equation** (no equal sign)... Can you explain me ?